# Navigate to different screen from a button in a header

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the new [React-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation) from react-native. I have the navigation as follows:

StackNavigator:

1. TabNavigator // HomeNavigation
2. TabNavigator // NotificationNavigation

Full code:

```
const MainNavigation = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeNavigation,
    },
    Notification: {
        screen: NotificationNavigation,
    }
});

const HomeNavigation = TabNavigator({
    AllPost: {
        screen: All,
    },
    ArticlePost: {
        screen: Article,
    },
    BusinessPost: {
        screen: Job,
    },
});

HomeNavigation.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    header: {
        right: <SearchNotification/>
    },
};

class SearchNotification extends React.Component {
    goToNotification = () => {
        this.props.navigate('Notification');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Icon name="md-search" style={styles.Icon}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notificationWrapper} onPress={this.goToNotification}>
                    <Icon name="md-notifications" style={styles.Icon}/>
                    <Text style={styles.number}>3</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const NotificationNavigation = TabNavigator({
    Comment: {
        screen: NotificationComment,
    },
    Follow: {
        screen: NotificationFollow,
    }
});
```

HomeNavigation has a header, and the header has a right component of SearchNotification. SearchNotification has an icon which on press I would like to go to the NotificatoinNavigation.

However, if I make changes to the header of HomeNavigation to this way, the SearchNotification is not displayed in the header.

```
HomeNavigation.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    header: {
        tintColor: 'white',
        style: {
            backgroundColor: '#2ec76e',
        },
        right: ({navigate}) => <SearchNotification navigate={navigate}/>
    },
};
```

How can I navigate to different screen from a button in a header?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the problem was (I think), inside the `navigationOptions` instead of using `navigations` I had to use `navigate`, and pass it as a props to the child (i.e. the **SearchNotification**).

So the final code looks like this:

```
HomeNavigation.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    header: ({navigate}) => ({
        right: (
            <SearchNotification navigate={navigate}/>
        ),
    }),
};
```

And within the **SearchNotification** component:

```
export default class SearchNotification extends React.Component {
    goToNotification = () => {
        this.props.navigate('Notification');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TouchableOpacity>
                    <Icon name="md-search" style={styles.Icon}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.notificationWrapper}
                                  onPress={() => this.props.navigate('Notification')}>
                    <Icon name="md-notifications" style={styles.Icon}/>
                    <Text style={styles.number}>3</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing navigate seems to be broken for me. I think passing navigation and then using the navigate function is correct like the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Code that worked for me:

```
import Header from '../Containers/Header'
.........................................
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Find User',
      headerRight: <Header navigation={navigation} />,
      headerStyle: styles.header
    })
```

And to move to other screen:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('UserDetail', {});
```

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me! A lifesaver.