# pass navigator to header

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I stumbled into the same problem found in the following question ([Navigate to different screen from a button in a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168623/navigate-to-different-screen-from-a-button-in-a-header)) which is duplicated on [Githb](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/286). The documentation pertaining to these features is found [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/headers#Configuring-the-Header) and [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigatorConfig).

I tried to implement the solution that was suggested but got the following error

`Objects are not valid as React child (found: object with keys{right}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

If you could help me out it would be much appreciated.

the offending components:

```
class Bookings extends Component {
   state = {
     BookingsList: [],
    }
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Bookings',
      headerStyle: {
       backgroundColor: '#49E841'
     },
     header:({ navigate }) => ({
       Right: (
        <HomeButton navigate={navigate}/>
        ),
      }),
    }
  //...More stuff that's not relevant
 }

 class HomeButton extends Component {
   render() {
   console.log(this.props)
   return (
   <TouchableHighlight
     onPress={() => this.props.navigate('Home')}
   >
     <View>
       <Image
          source={require('./Assets/home.png')}
       />
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
  )}
 };

 const RallyMobileNavigator = StackNavigator({
   Home: { screen: RallyMobile },
   LogIn: { screen: LogIn },
   Bookings: { screen: Bookings},
   Menu: { screen: Menu },
   },{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'screen'
  });
```

Here's the stack trace:

[image: stack trace]

Comment: Can we see the whole stacktrace?

Comment: I added it for you, Hopefully that's what you are looking for, the Node server console has the following as well: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON   at parse (<anonymous>)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)