# React Navigation navigate to new screen from button in custom header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, react-navigation

I'm using `React-Navigation` and i created my custom header. I used:

```
navigationOptions: {
    header: <Header />
}
```

Which `<Header />` is imported from the path.

I have an `TouchableOpacity` inside header which i want to use to navigate to another tab! I tried to use `this.props.navigation.navigate("_TabTwo")` but i get an error:

> can't find variable navigate

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168623/navigate-to-different-screen-from-a-button-in-a-header) but it's about the default header! The point is my `<Header />` is a **custom component**!

How can I navigate from a button in my header to another screen?

> Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your `<Header />` component

Comment: @SGhaleb Updated - Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use navigationOptions like so and pass the navigation as prop to the Header component

```
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({ 
  header: <Header navigation={navigation} />
})
```

The Header component is not a screen but a part of the navigationOptions so it doesn't inherit the navigation prop, you need to pass it manually